# How to set cookie in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to set cookie but unable to set
i have also used this `public $components = array('Cookie');`

i used in UsersController `$this->Cookie->write('name', 'Larry');`
echo on another controller `echo $this->Cookie->read('name');`

but there is no result

please suggest how to set cookie in cake php

thank Sanjib

Comment: may i know the reason for minus point?

Comment: Did you check header for the cookie? Is it set or not?

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you used this tutorial for cookies: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html

What you probably missed is setting up the cookieComponent, this of course is necessary in order for you to use cookies.

```
public $components = array('Cookie');

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Cookie->name = 'baker_id';
    $this->Cookie->time = 3600;  // or '1 hour'
    $this->Cookie->path = '/bakers/preferences/';
    $this->Cookie->domain = 'example.com';
    $this->Cookie->secure = true;  // i.e. only sent if using secure HTTPS
    $this->Cookie->key = 'qSI232qs*&sXOw!adre@34SAv!@*(XSL#$%)asGb$@11~_+!@#HKis~#^';
    $this->Cookie->httpOnly = true;
    $this->Cookie->type('aes');
}
```

Comment: Then could you please write down the entire code you use for the cookies?

Comment: i have used the entire code got an warning message
`You must use cipher or rijndael for cookie encryption type [CORE\Cake\Controller\Component\CookieComponent.php, line 355]`

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out

```
$this->Cookie->type('aes');
```

you should find the problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppController `src\Controller\AppController.php`

put `var $components = array('Cookie');`

or you can set and retrieve cookie using original PHP.

Answer (score 0):

For people using CakePHP 4.x: Instead of using the cookie component, you now need to set a cookie to the `Response` object and fetch it via the `Request` object:

```php
// Create cookie and set it to the Response object
$cookie = (new Cookie('name'))
    ->withValue('Larry');
$this->setResponse($this->getResponse()->withCookie($testCookie));
```

```php
// Fetch a cookie's value from the Request object
$name = $this->getRequest()->getCookie('name'); // 'Larry'
```

Note that setting cookies will not work when using `debug()` or other output (e.g. `echo`), as headers cannot be sent if any output is already sent. You should get a warning about this as well.

For more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64010320/1973005), or check the documentation on [setting cookies](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-cookies) and [getting cookies](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#cookies)
.